# Google Chrome & Opera browsers got stuck and hangs

Tags: ubuntu

I am using latest version **Chrome & Opera** browsers in **(64-bit) Ubuntu 17.10**. Most of the times Chrome & Opera get stuck and hangs whole system.  Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming... :c

Answer (score -3):

1. How much RAM is installed on the computer? not less than 4G
2. Are proprietary drivers installed on the graphics card? If not, install.
3. Disable Hardware Acceleration Mode

in Chrome - Launch Chrome, then select `“Menu”`  > `“Settings“`.
Scroll down to the bottom and select the `“Advanced”` option.
Scroll to the bottom and toggle `“Use hardware acceleration when available”` off as desired.

in Opera - Uncheck Use hardware acceleration when available under the System heading

4. Use most light browsers - such as Slimjet (instead Chrome) and Vivaldi (instead Opera).

I have been using Slimjet and Vivaldi for 2 years already - even with 3G memory there were no hangs